# Collapsible box not showing all of my text in html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not going to feign intelligence, I'm stupid when it comes to this. I have a collapsible box that when  opened has two more boxes in it neither box inside shows what it's supposed to. But, if I open the box inside then close the box that has the inside one and re-open it it shows all of my text. Can someone help me fix this so they don't have to open the boxes twice?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
div.a {
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="a">

.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 360px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a">
<h1> Staffs</h1>
<button class="collapsible"> Staff guides here</button>
<div class="content">
<p>Ice</p>
<button class="collapsible">Building</button>
<div class="content">
<p><style>
div.a {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<div class="a">
<h1> Wind staff tutorial </h1>
<p>So you want to upgrade the staffs? Follow this and all my other tutorials.</p>
<ol>
<li>Firstly, you want to have the staff<em> <strong>built.</strong></em></li>
<li>Then, you want to go to the <em> <strong>CRAZY PLACE. </strong></em></li>
<li>Now, you want to go to the wind part of the Crazy Place and look up. You should see symbols when you look up.</li>
<li>Now, you want to shoot them to where it looks like this at the bottom of the cage (Inner is nearest to thing in the middle) but of course it has to be with the <em> <strong> Wind staff </em> </strong></li>
</ol>
<p><br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <img src="http://www.kronorium.com/img/wind_staff.png" alt="" width="'120&quot;" height="240" /></p>
  </div> </p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible"> Upgrading</button>
<div class="content">
<p>INSERT NEW CODE HERE</p>
</div>
<p>The Ice Staff is one of, if not the best staffs that's easy to get and upgrade. When shot it freezes zombies.  </p>
</div>
<h1> Map of Origins </h1>
<p> By ZedzDEMIZie on Imgur</p>
<button class="collapsible"> Origins map image</button>
<!-- Remember to fix gray background. This can be done by modding the div-->
<div class="content">
<img alt="Origins map by ZedzDEMIZie" src="origins.jpg" width="500"> 
</div>
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Sometimes, isolating the problem helps you figure it out on your own.

Comment: @SwimmerF That is a reproducible example. Just copy and paste it into a test environment such as JSFiddle or JSBin.

Comment: @AezignSpace Reproducible? Yes. Minimal? No.

Comment: @SwimmerF How is it not minimal? It has the CSS and HTML required for it to function, and some example content. Nothing extra.

Comment: @AezignSpace There is the stray `<div class="a">` in the style tag that you point out in your answer. It turns out to be is unrelated to the problem at hand, but tidying up code before submitting a question is good practice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you lock the height of `.content` to a fixed pixel value at the time you open the box. This is needed for the transition effect you use, but creates the problem you describe.

A possible workaround is to set the height to a variable amount after the transition effect.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      setTimeout(function() {
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      }, 50)
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      setTimeout(function() {
        content.style.maxHeight = "fit-content";
      }, 250)
    }
  });
}
```

```css
div.a {
  text-align: center;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: auto;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="a">
    <h1> Staffs</h1>
    <button class="collapsible"> Staff guides here</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Ice</p>
      <button class="collapsible">Building</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          <div class="a">
            <h1> Wind staff tutorial </h1>
            <p>So you want to upgrade the staffs? Follow this and all my other tutorials.</p>
            <ol>
              <li>Firstly, you want to have the staff<em> <strong>built.</strong></em></li>
              <li>Then, you want to go to the <em> <strong>CRAZY PLACE. </strong></em></li>
              <li>Now, you want to go to the wind part of the Crazy Place and look up. You should see symbols when you look up.</li>
              <li>Now, you want to shoot them to where it looks like this at the bottom of the cage (Inner is nearest to thing in the middle) but of course it has to be with the <em> <strong> Wind staff </em> </strong>
              </li>
            </ol>
            <p>
              <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
              <img src="http://www.kronorium.com/img/wind_staff.png" alt="" width="'120&quot;" height="240" />
            </p>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>
      <button class="collapsible"> Upgrading</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>INSERT NEW CODE HERE</p>
      </div>
      <p>The Ice Staff is one of, if not the best staffs that's easy to get and upgrade. When shot it freezes zombies. </p>
    </div>
    <h1> Map of Origins </h1>
    <p> By ZedzDEMIZie on Imgur</p>
    <button class="collapsible"> Origins map image</button>
    <div class="content">
      <img alt="Origins map by ZedzDEMIZie" src="origins.jpg" width="500">
    </div>
</body>

</html>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution breaks the transition effect, but fixes the problem. You'll need to find another way to apply the transition effect.

Set `content.style.maxHeight` to `"fit-content"`.

Set `height` of `.collapsible` to `auto`.

Remove the stray `<div class='a'>` tag that is sitting inside the `<style>` tag. (How did that get there?)